# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

Tags: php, parsing

From this [Simple Dom Site](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

```
if(isset($html->'div#sidebar')) 
{
    $sidebarFile = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\final\wordpress\sidebar.php';
    $openSidebarFile = fopen($sidebarFile,'a');
    foreach($html->find('div#sidebar')) as $e)
    {
        $html ->find('div[id=sidebar]', 0) -> innertext;
        $inputSidebar = $e->outertext;
        fwrite($openSidebarFile, "\n" .inputSidebar "\n");
    }
}
```

From the documentation:
it says:

```
// Determine whether a attribute exist? 
if(isset($e->href)) 
        echo 'href exist!';
```

Comment: Please mention which line you are getting this error, otherwise please post the full page code.

Comment: I insert the `find` and I get this error `Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context`

Comment: all these errors have line numbers, GIVE US CONTEXT!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here I'll just correct them inline:

```
if($html->find('div#sidebar')) 
{
    $sidebarFile = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\final\wordpress\sidebar.php';
    $openSidebarFile = fopen($sidebarFile,'a');
    foreach($html->find('div#sidebar') as $e)
    {
        $html ->find('div[id=sidebar]', 0) -> innertext;
        $inputSidebar = $e->outertext;
        fwrite($openSidebarFile, "\n" .inputSidebar "\n");
    }
}
```

Now, what was changed?  The first `if`, and the `foreach`.  The if used the wrong function, and the wrong check for empty.  The foreach had mismatched `()` braces.

Answer (score 1):

Is `$html->'div#sidebar'` really what you wanted? Where's `find`?

Also, you can only use `isset` with variables (or similar things such as array access), not function return values. Use `empty` instead.